# Obtaining the sum of message byte lengths on the application layer by the Omnet++ result collection

Tags: omnet++

Suppose in a wireless network with 25 nodes, we have a scenario where some of each node sends messages to some other nodes according to a routing protocol such as AODV. We simulate this network. After finishing the simulation, how to obtain the sum of messages byte length on the application layer by the Omnet++ result collection? For each node, we must have two metrics, a metric for sent message byte lengths (e.g. totalSentMessageByteLengths) and a metric for received message byte lengths (e.g. totalReceivedMessageByteLengths). If retransmission occurs, it should be summed once for the receiver side, summed the incorrect message byte lengths, and the correct message byte lengths for the sender side. If a node has more than an application, all the message byte lengths generated by all applications of the same node must be calculated. An instace code for a node in omnetpp.ini:

```
*.hostA.numApps = 2
*.hostA.app[0].typename = "UdpBasicApp"
*.hostA.app[0].destAddresses = "hostB"
*.hostA.app[0].destPort = 5000
*.hostA.app[0].messageLength = 1000B
*.hostA.app[0].sendInterval = exponential(12ms)
*.hostA.app[0].packetName = "UDPData"

*.hostA.app[0].typename = "TcpBasicApp"
*.hostA.app[0].destAddresses = "hostC"
*.hostA.app[0].destPort = 5001
*.hostA.app[0].messageLength = 1024B
*.hostA.app[0].sendInterval = exponential(45ms)
*.hostA.app[0].packetName = "TCPData"
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost all application module has a `packetSent` or `packetReceived` statistics that gathers the mentioned data. So in short. Turn on scale statistics gathering on these apps.

```
**.app[*].*.scalar-recording = true
```